# How to extract info from varying table entries: Text vs. DIV vs. SPAN

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I am new to python and searched the internet to find an answer to my problem, but so far I failed...

**The problem**: My aim is to extract data from websites. More specifically, from the tables in these websites. The relevant snippet from the website-code you find in "*data*" in my python-code example here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<table class="ds-table">
        <tr>
          <td class="data-label">year of birth:</td>
                        <td class="data-value">1994</td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="data-label">reporting period:</td>
          <td class="data-value">
            <span class="editable" id="c-scope_beginning_date">
              ?                </span>
            &nbsp;-&nbsp;
            <span  class="editable" id="c-scope_ending_date">
              ?                </span>
          </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="data-label">reporting cycle:</td>
          <td class="data-value">
            <span class="editable" id="c-periodicity">
              -                </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td class="data-label">grade:</td>
              <td class="data-value">1.3, upper 10% of class</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="data-label">status:</td>
              <td class="data-value"></td>
              </tr>
      </table>
        <table class="ds-table">
             <tr>
              <td class="data-label">economics:</td>
                <td class="data-value"><span class="positive-value"></span></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td class="data-label">statistics:</td>
              <td class="data-value"><span class="negative-value"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
          <td class="data-label">social:</td>
          <td class="data-value"><div id="music_id" class="trigger"><span class="negative-value"></span></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="data-label">misc:</td>
           <td class="data-value">
            <div id="c_assurance" class="">
                <span class="positive-value"></span>                </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="data-label">recommendation:</td>
            <td class="data-value">
                <span class="negative-value"></span>                </td>
        </tr>  
                  </table>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
```

For the *class="data-label"* so far I successfully implemented...

```
box_cdl = []
for i, cdl in enumerate(soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'data-label'})):
    box_cdl.append(cdl.contents[0])
print box_cdl
```

...which extracts the text from the columns, in the (for me satisfying) output:

```
[u'year of birth:',
 u'reporting period:',
 u'reporting cycle:',
 u'grade:',
 u'status:',
 u'economics:',
 u'statistics:',
 u'social:',
 u'misc:',
 u'recommendation:']
```

Where I get stuck is the part for `class="data-value"` with the *div*- and *span*-fields and that some of the relevant information is hidden in the *span-class*. Moreover, the amount of the *tr*-rows can change from website to website, e.g. "status" comes after "reporting cycle" (instead of "grade").

However, when I do...

```
box_cdv = []
for j, cdv in enumerate(soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'data-value'})):
   box_cdv.append(cdv.contents[0])
print box_cdv
```

...I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-53-7d5c095cf647>", line 3, in <module>
    box_cdv.append(cdv.contents[0])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

What I would like to get instead is something like this (corresponding to the above "*data*"-example):

```
[u'1994',
 u'? &nbsp;-&nbsp; ?',
 u'-',
 u'1.3, upper 10% of class',
 u'',
 u'positive-value',
 u'negative-value',
 u'negative-value',
 u'positive-value',
 u'negative-value']
```

**The Question**: how can I extract this information and collect the relevant data from each *tr*-row, given that the adequate extraction-code depends on the type of the category (year of birth, reporting period, ..., recommendation)?

**Or, asking differently**: what code extracts me, depending on the category (year of birth, reporting period, ..., recommendation), the corresponding value (1994, ..., negative-value)?

Since the amount and the type of the table-entries can differ between websites, a simple "on the i-th entry do the following" procedure is not applicable. The thing I am looking for I think is something like "if you find the text "recommendation:", then extract the class-type from the span-field", I guess. But unfortunately I do not have any clue how to translate that into python-language.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because one of the tags don't have any `children` so the `contents` list gives an error when searching for that index.

You can approeach this on the following way:

1) Search for the `data-label` tags;

2) Find the next `TD` sibling;

3 A) Check of the sibling has text;

3 A) 1) If so create a dict entry with `data-label` as the key and the sibling text as its value;

3 A) B) If not check if the sibling first child have a class containing -value`

4) Parse the data.

Example:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

result = {}

for tag in soup.find_all("td", { "class" : "data-label" }):
    NextSibling = tag.find_next("td", { "class" : "data-value" }).get_text(strip = True)
    if not NextSibling and len(tag.find_next("td").select('span[class*=-value]')) > 0:
        NextSibling = tag.find_next("td").select('span[class*=-value]')[0]["class"][0]
    result[tag.get_text(strip = True)] = NextSibling

print (result)
```

Result:

> {
>       'year of birth:': '1994',
>       'reporting period:': '?-?',
>       'reporting cycle:': '-',
>       'grade:': '1.3, upper 10% of class',
>       'status:': '',
>       'economics:': 'positive-value',
>       'statistics:': 'negative-value',
>       'social:': 'negative-value',
>       'misc:': 'positive-value',
>       'recommendation:': 'negative-value'
>   }